# Selenium c#: Execute correct jquery

Tags: c#, selenium

Im trying to execute jquery from selenium to change the visibility of a object, I have the next code but it's not working, does anybody knows the error?

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript(                
           "document.querySelector('input[type='file']').style.display = 'block';"
         );
```

Comment: What is not working?  The C# bit, the Selenium bit, or the javascript?

Comment: The problem is with the javascript, this is the error: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the quotes, I've already fixed:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript(
         @"document.querySelector('input[type=""file""]').style.display = 'block';"

            );
```